# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a differential equation contains complex numbers. These complex numbers are constants A and B.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# intinialize values
x0=0
y0=1
xf=2
h=0.1
n=200
y=np.zeros([n])
t=np.zeros([n]) 
y[0]=y0
t[0]=x0
t=np.linspace(x0,xf,n)

gamma=1.0

width=1.0

v_g=1.0

L=1.0

k=1

r=1.0

C=1j

A=((8*np.pi)**(1.0/4.0)/(np.sqrt(width*L)))*(- 
C/2*np.pi)*np.sqrt(gamma*v_g*L/2)

B=(k**2)+C*k*r-((width**2)*(r**2)/4)+r*v_g*t*(width**2/2)-v_g**2*t**2*      
(width**2/4)+k**2/width**2

for i in range(1,n):
   t[i]=t[i-1]+h
   slope=A*np.exp(B)-(1/2)*(y[i-1])
   y[i]=y[i-1]+h*slope
plt.plot(t,y,'-')
```

Can anyone help me to explain the problem and give a suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I'm getting this error message **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence**.

Comment: Please add full stack trace.

Comment: `B` is an array because `t` is an array., is this what you want? So the `slope` is an array too and that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you problem solved